# insert $duration variable inside another line of code in a sh file

Tags: zenity

I found out about byzanz-record which can record your desktop and get the result as a gif, flash or other, I want to make a GUI for personal use but I can't seem to get it working up until now I only have this

```
#!/bin/bash
duration=$(yad --title "duration" --entry --text "please enter the duration in seconds")
x=$(yad --title "x possition" --entry --text "please enter the x posittion")
y=$(yad --title "y possition" --entry --text "please enter the y posittion")
with=$(yad --title "with" --entry --text "please enter the with")
height=$(yad --title "height" --entry --text "please enter the height")
name=$(yad --title "name" --entry --text "please enter the name or path for the file without the extension")


byzanz-record --duration=$echo $duration --x='$(echo $x)' --y='$(echo $y)' --width='$(echo $with)' --height='$(echo $height)' '$(echo $name)'.gif
```

as you can see I want to input the variables duration,x,y,with,height and name after the '=' sign in the command at the bottom, (**OPTIONAL**) if you can, can you tell me how to put the multiple windows in a form I have yad and zenity

Answer (score 0):

```
All=$(yad --form --columns 2 --text "Please fill the form" \
    --field 'Duration' ''  --field "Y position" ''         \
    --field Height '' --field "X position" ''              \
    --field With '' --field Name '')
IFS=\| read Duration Y Height X With Name <<< "$All"
byzanz-record --duration="$Duration" --x="$X" --y="$Y" --width="$With" --height="$Height" "$Name.gif"
```

Comment: is that an answer?